# Invalid index 0, size is 0. Can not add to arrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have this code

```
ArrayList<File> internalPaths = new ArrayList<File>();
ArrayList<File> externalPaths = new ArrayList<File>();

for (int i = 0; i < pathCounter; i++) {

    Log.e("PK", Integer.toString(pathCounter));
    if (i == 0) {
        // first path
        String path = pathString.substring(commaPositions[i],
            commaPositions[i + 1] + 1);

        if (path.length() > 7 && path.substring(0,8).contains("storage")) {
            externalPaths.add(new File(path));
        } else {
            internalPaths.add(new File(path));
        }
    }
}
```

It is failing exactly on part

```
else {
    internalPaths.add(new File(path));
}
```

With exception:

> Invalid index 0, size is 0.

I wonder how it is possible, as I have no problem with adding to `externalPaths`, but with `internalPaths` there is this error.

Comment: How do you declare commaPositions???

Comment: Are you sure your code is up to date. Can you identify the precise line, not block, at fault ?

Comment: Sorry, edited. Now it's more clear.

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind for me is that the File constructor doesnt like your path... can you check what the path-variable actually contains here?

Comment: Did you debug with breakpoints?

Comment: Post your Logcat error here.

Comment: post full exception as in ex.printStackTrace();

Comment: where to declare commaPositions...???

Comment: What's the error dude ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (path.length() > 7
                        && path.substring(0,8).contains("storage")) {
```

The substring index of 0, 8 might be causing problems on strings shorter then 8 chars. Also you may need to handle empty string case.

Comment: The `substring()` call will cause no problems on a `String` of length 7, as the second parameter is exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

> It is failing exactly on part

```
else {
    internalPaths.add(new File(path));
}
```

InternalPaths is an ArrayList which is initialized (not a NullPointerException) and its `add` method is supposed to append an item at the end of the array and not `put` it in a specific place (indexed position). Therefore, the problem should be in the `File`'s constructor. Debug and check the value of the `path`. I bet it is an empty string. Figure out how it can be initialized to such value.